# how to escape a variable in c#

Tags: c#, hex

I hope the title is clear enough, but what I want is  like this:

```
string hello = "0012";
string escapedHello = "\u" + hello;
```

The reason for this, is beacuse, the program is for printing labels on a brother ptouch printer, which have a template stored, and it can print the variables from the file, i will create with my program.

My program works now, but not the "smartest" way. Right now it is a certain amount of length, so i append some spaces on the values, that don't live up the required length.
The length of the value, is stored in hex, and right now, i Write the value length with:

```
\u0004
```

I want to take the values i get via. my program, and get the length, and write it as hex, in the file, because then the length will be dymanic, and the text the printer prints, will  be more enjoyable to read.

Here is the code for my program:

```
    static void Main(string[] lines)
    {

        //Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"C:\HireLabel");
        //string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("var.txt");
        string[] hexstrings = new string[lines.Length-1];

        string[] replaceWith = { "Modelnavn1111111", "Variant111111111111111111111", "Bchass", "Nmplade", "Year", "color1111111111111" };
        string binFile = "\u001bia\u0003^II^TS001^ONModel\0^DI\u0010\0Modelnavn1111111^ONVariant\0^DI\u001c\0Variant111111111111111111111^ONbchass\0^DI\u0006\0Bchass^ONnmplade\0^DI\u0007\0Nmplade^ONyear\0^DI\u0004\0Year^ONColor\0^DI\u0012\0color1111111111111^FF";


        for (int i = 0; i <replaceWith.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            hexstrings[i] = @"\u" + lines[i].Length.ToString("X4");
            Console.WriteLine(hexstrings[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < replaceWith.Length; i++)
        {
            while (replaceWith[i].Length > lines[i].Length)
            {
                lines[i] += " ";
            }

            binFile = binFile.Replace(replaceWith[i], lines[i]);
        }

        //File.WriteAllText("C:\\HireLabel\\print.bin", binFile);
        //Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C C:\\HireLabel\\spool.exe C:\\HireLabel\\print.bin " + "\"" + lines[replaceWith.Length] + "\"");


    }
```

The program write now, writes for an example "0007" in the console, and it should give some wierd chinese looking letters, instead of the numbers. but the number is the number in hex, so that part is converted right.

Comment: Not really clear what you want do achieve. Do you expect `escapedHello` to contain the single character '\u0012'?

Comment: @KlausGütter Exactly :)

Comment: To me it does not make sense to use the length of a string to determine which unicode character to write. Am I missing something? If you just want to write the length as hex, remove the `\u`

Comment: The printer uses the hex to dertimine how long the word is, so right now, the length is "hard coded" which means the text, is unneceraly small sometimes :)

Comment: This would be `var hello = 0x0012; string escapedHello = new string((char)hello, 1);`
You are not writing a text file, so `File.WriteAllText` is inappropriate.

Comment: Here is an explanation of the long "binFile" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oy2_F3CrLeM

Comment: @KlausGütter I will try it out, and let you know if it works

Comment: @KlausGütter it worked :D thank you!